# Is there any difference between 'ajna chakra' and the 'third eye' of a human?

Tags: terminology, chakras, eye

When I try to know more about the stages of a yogi, I read more discussions about a chakra named Ajna. There are numerous mentions of this chakra in several scriptures. Lalitha Sahastranaama also [contains](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Lalitha_Sahasranamam) the name.

> **Agna chakarantharalastha**: She who lives in between two eyelids in the form of she who orders
>
> **Rudra grandhi vibhedini**: She who breaks the ties of Rudra grandhi i. e she who helps us cross the ties due to our violent thoughts and
> nature

Many discussions on online forums and even answers on our site say that **Ajna chakra** and **third eye** are the same.

But, in scriptures, many entities, although same at a gross level, there can be subtle differences. I am wondering whether it is the same with the case of these two words. One is called chakra and the other refers to it as an eye.

Is there any subtle difference between them both?